# How to translate フォー・ダークネス

Tags: translation

I'm not sure how to translate フォー・ダークネス (alternatively 闇のもの) to English as " ___ Darkness ".

This is the name of some monster. It might be some sort of word play or some reference to the Shoggoth. I cannot tell.

The フォー part sounds like: four, for, foe, pho, fore, foo, ...
but I don't think any of them match.

I thought maybe "full" but that's written with フル

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Looks like it's a name attributed to a set of monsters

> 闇のもの【フォー・ダークネス】 の１体 ダーク・ショゴスだ

Comment: Which game? Is there more dialogue or a more extensive description you can find about the monster in the game? Given the Japanese name, it's likely just *foe darkness*.

Comment: @JansthcirlU I found this in a manga. It looks like a black Ditto pokemon. It was referred to as 闇のもの【フォー・ダークネス】の一部 at first, then 闇のもの or フォー・ダークネス later on.

Comment: Then it's certainly *foe darkness*.

Comment: @JansthcirlU hmm, it feels off but I guess I don't have other choices. Thanks

Comment: Context is very important to answer a question like this. Please do not hide the title.

Comment: @naruto Bravo for figuring out the title just from this much information. But I tried to write a self-contained question not requiring people to read the manga first before attempting to answer.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but we often see questions that require contexts the asker never felt the need for. (Examples [1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/69679/5010), [2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/57124/5010) and [3](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73786/5010)). We can often save lots of time just with a title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this is from 時間停止勇者. I initially thought this フォー is "four" (i.e., ショゴス is one of the four mid-bosses collectively called ダークネス) because having four mid-bosses is a very common trope (aka [四天王](https://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E5%9B%9B%E5%A4%A9%E7%8E%8B) or ["Elite Four"](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EliteFour)).

However, in [a recent episode](https://seiga.nicovideo.jp/watch/mg489848?track=ct_episode), I found that a small unnamed enemy is also called a フォー・ダークネス, so now I think this フォー is **"for"** (i.e., beings that work "for darkness").

[image]

I doubt "foe" is relevant simply because this word is way too difficult to average Japanese readers.

Either way, we may have to forget how it sounds to English speakers, and you do not necessarily have to translate something like this literally.

Comment: I had the same thought process, but I started having doubts. I think "for darkness" is more correct, but it kind of doesn't fit perfectly in the English sentences. I'll live with it.

PS: I prefer to translate the katakana rather than the kanji just in case the author plans to use that for some reference (he frequently does) or something else.